# What is the maximum possible priority value of an xfrm policy in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ipsec

```
      ip xfrm policy { deleteall | list } [ dir DIR ] [ SELECTOR ] [ index INDEX ]
                    [ action ACTION ] [ priority PRIORITY ]
```

The man page talks about the default value, but not about the minimum and maximum values.

```
priority PRIORITY
             priority is a number. Default priority is set on zero.
```

Can someone please let me know what their minimum and maximum values are and which header file I can find them in?

Comment: There aren't any (minimum or maximum values).  Currently, any 32-bit unsigned integer will work.  Zero, the default priority, is also the *highest* priority (as in most preferred); higher values indicate lower interest/preference/priority.  See `priority` member in `struct xfrm_policy` in the Linux kernel, for example in [net/xfrm/xfrm_policy.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/xfrm/xfrm_policy.c).

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose you should probably post that as an answer!